# Ruby Docs "::" vs "#"

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby.

Can someone explain to me what the difference is between the characters preceding methods listed for a class in Ruby's documentation?

Here's an example: For the String class, the characters `::` before `::new` and `::try_convert` versus the `#` before methods like `#chomp`, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It specifies the "level" of methods. `::` for class-level methods, `#` for instance-level methods.

For example, when you see `String::new`, you know you have to call it on a `String` class directly

```
s = String.new # silly example, because nobody does that.
```

But when you see `String#gsub`, you understand that you need an *instance* of `String` to call this method

```
String.gsub # uh-oh, won't work

s = "I like coffee"
s.gsub('coffee', 'tea') # => "I like tea"
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I googled all over the place for an answer to this and couldn't find any resources.  Where would you suggest I look in the future for questions like this?

Comment: Stackoverflow is a good place, if thorough googling doesn't yield useful results.